Signing and verifying signatures with different key lengths RSA C#
I understand that in a RSA algorithm, the key length determines how difficult is for someone to break the encryption or to generate a fake signature. What is unclear for me is why am I allowed to create a digital signature with a 1024 key length and then verifying with a 2048 length and get a match.
I am using RSACryptoServiceProvider with a key length of 1024 to sing and then a  RSACryptoServiceProvider with a key length of 2048 to verify (or the other way around) and I always get a match.
Code to sign
        private static string SignData(string originalMessage, string privateKey, int keyLength)
        {
            using var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keyLength);
            rsa.FromXmlString(privateKey);

            var rsaFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(rsa);
            rsaFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");

            var sha256Managed = new SHA256Managed();
            var signedHashValue = rsaFormatter.CreateSignature(sha256Managed.ComputeHash(new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(originalMessage)));
            var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(signedHashValue);

            return signature;
        }

Code to verify
       private static bool VerifyData(string stringSigned, byte[] signature, XmlElement rsaPublicKey, int keyLength)
        {
            using var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keyLength);
            rsa.FromXmlString(rsaPublicKey.OuterXml);

            var rsaDeformatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(rsa);
            rsaDeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");

            var sha256Managed = new SHA256Managed();
            if (rsaDeformatter.VerifySignature(sha256Managed.ComputeHash(new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(stringSigned)), signature))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

Code to test
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int signingKey = 1024;
            const int verifyingKey = 2048;
            const string originalMessage = "textToCheck";

            var rsaForSigning = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(signingKey);
            var publicKey = rsaForSigning.ToXmlString(false);
            var privateKey = rsaForSigning.ToXmlString(true);

            // Sign with private key
            var signature = SignData(originalMessage, privateKey, signingKey);

            // Verify signature with public key
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(publicKey);


            var correctSignature = VerifyData(originalMessage, Convert.FromBase64String(signature), doc.DocumentElement, verifyingKey);
            if (correctSignature)
                Console.WriteLine($"{originalMessage} - Signature is valid");
            else
                Console.WriteLine($"{originalMessage} - Signature is NOT valid");

            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }


Because FromXmlString will overwrite randomly generated RSA parameters. The keyLength you passed in here has no effect at all.

Correct, the key size is determined by the modulus size for RSA, so when a modulus is retrieved from either the public or private key then the key size changes automatically.
